# Why goagent can work through google app engine but not '*.appspot.com'

Tags: google-app-engine

I can access some forbidden websites in China like Youtube, Facebook, Twitter by GoAgent, which uses the Google App Engine, but why can't I access my own app published in `*.appspot.com` without any proxy or VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because GoAgent connects the servers of Google in Beijing and HongKong, not the servers of *.appspot.com which in US.  Many servers of Google can serve Google App Engine services even if they originally not in *.appspot.com servers.